# How to establish internet connection via VB if I use VPN on host?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, vpn

I have host Windows machine with VPN connection and Internet connection and also I have Linux machine on VB.

Linux machine has NAT connection with host and great works with VPN sites. But one problem is here, I can`t browse other sites via my VB. There are not available.
But on host machine all works well.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official VB documentation "**6.3.3. NAT limitations**": https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#nat-limitations

> Protocols other than TCP and UDP are not supported. **This means some VPN products (e.g. PPTP from Microsoft) cannot be used**. There are other VPN products which use simply TCP and UDP.

Try to use **Bridged networking**, it must add your virtual machine to the LAN if it is possible, and to the Internet.